# Meteor application not appearing on AWS using Mup deployment & NGINX

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, meteor, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a Meteor application to an Amazon Web Services instance using Meteor Up (mup). I followed this guide https://sergelobatch.com/beginners-guide-to-deploying-a-meteor-app-to-an-aws-server-with-meteor-up/ which has taken me so far successfully until this roadblock.

Mup setup and Mup deploy are both running successfully. Once I visit the ip through a browser I receive a refused to connect error.

[image: AWS inbound settings]

Meteor Version 1.5.4

Mup 1.4.5

Here is my mup.js

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      // TODO: set host address, username, and authentication method
      host: '54.206.11.xx',
      username: 'ubuntu',
      pem: '~/.ssh/MyClient-Staging.pem'
      // password: 'server-password'
      // or neither for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
  },

  app: {
    // TODO: change app name and path
    name: 'MyClient',
    path: '../',

    servers: {
      one: {},
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },

    env: {
      // TODO: Change to your app's url
      // If you are using ssl, it needs to start with https://
      ROOT_URL: 'http://54.206.11.xx',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://mongodb/meteor',
      MONGO_OPLOG_URL: 'mongodb://mongodb/local',
    },

    docker: {
      // change to 'abernix/meteord:base' if your app is using Meteor 1.4 - 1.5
      // image: 'abernix/meteord:node-8.4.0-base',
      image: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    },

    // Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
    // You might need to disable it on CI servers
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },

  mongo: {
    version: '3.4.1',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  },

  // (Optional)
  // Use the proxy to setup ssl or to route requests to the correct
  // app when there are several apps

  // proxy: {
  //   domains: 'mywebsite.com,www.mywebsite.com',

  //   ssl: {
  //     // Enable Let's Encrypt
  //     letsEncryptEmail: 'email@domain.com'
  //   }
  // }
};
```

On further inspection it would appear something is forcing the root url to  HTTPS, i'm not sure how this is happening.

Update:

I'm now using Nginx to serve my files as a work around to this https problem. The problem now is I'm only seeing the nginx welcome page where I should actually be seeing my app.

Here is my sites-enabled/configuration

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           mysite.com;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/app.dev.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/app.dev.error.log;

  location ~* "^/[a-z0-9]{40}\.(css|js)$" {
    root /opt/appName/app/programs/web.browser;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location ~ "^/packages" {
    root /opt/appName/app/programs/web.browser/packages;
    access_log off;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

Here I can see the docker containers running.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        NAMES
2e0124d3fb74        mup-mefleetclient:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'bash $M…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp         MyClient
b880f60e7758        mongo:3.4.1                "/entrypoint.sh mong…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        127.0.0.1:27017->27017/tcp   mongodb
root@ip-172-31-4-125:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled#
```

Comment: If you type your IP in a navigator (http:// 54.206.11.68), it gets rerouted to httpS (https:// 54.206.11.68). And httpS (443) is not available in your aws inboud settings. You should try to open up the port to see if you can display something...

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for you help. I've now edited the inbound settings to include https on port 443, unfortunately i'm still seeing a refused to connect error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit of this problem was an npm package called 'force-ssl' installed on the project. Removing the package solved the issue and the project was viewable online.